# In Chrome, the form is not submitted with two fields

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, firefox, submit

I have been working with html + js + css recently and found a very strange issue in chrome and firefox.

I have a form with a few fields, but it does not submit on pressing enter. I was wondering what could be the reason. It is submitted properly if I remove all the fields and keep only one.

Is it really a chrome/firefox bug or am I dreaming?

**Code 1:** (works properly, form is submitted on enter)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code 2:** (does not work, form is not submitted on enter)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Demos:**

1 field: http://jsbin.com/IFowenev/4/edit (works properly, form is submitted on enter)

2 fields: http://jsbin.com/IFowenev/3/edit (does not work, form is not submitted on enter)

Comment: do they really matter?

Comment: had already tried `name` and `id` attributes. nothing happens.

Comment: As far as I remember form only autosubmits on enter if it has a single field. Why would that be a bug? I do not think any browser gives you any guarantees about enter handling.

If you want to be sure, you can always handle it in JS.

Comment: when is the form supposed to be submitted when you have 2 fields? I don't see a method to submit. When there is only one field some of the browser assumes that on enter key it is to be submitted, even though it is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [quotation for `jQuery`'s submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) function...

> Depending on the browser, the Enter key may only cause a form
>   submission if the form has exactly one text field, or only when there
>   is a submit button present. The interface should not rely on a
>   particular behavior for this key unless the issue is forced by
>   observing the keypress event for presses of the Enter key.

Now if you want to"auto-submit" the form you can only have one input text element or simply add a submit button to the form.

Answer (score 1):

> When there is only one single-line text input field in a form, the
> user agent should accept Enter in that field as a request to submit
> the form.
>
> [Hypertext Markup Language - 2.0](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2)

For reliable results, I recommend using JavaScript to submit on enter.